# "Such lyrics as" vs "Lyrics such as"

Tags: inversion, comparative-constructions

> The optimism of **such lyrics as** “Tyrant Man shall be o’erthrown” and “Riches more than mind can picture” galvanizes the animals’ agitation.

Are the words in bold reversed in sequence? Are they actually meant to be **lyrics such as**? If it is so, please explain why it is in such sequence; and if not, please explain too, on how I should interpret the sentence.

Comment: Don't feel you need to apologize.  'Basic' questions are very often the hardest to understand -- and to explain! Welcome to ELL!

Answer (score 1):

Because ***men*** is a much more common plural noun than ***lyrics***, I'll use that in my usage chart...

[[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heYuL.png)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of%20men%20such%20as%2Cof%20such%20men%20as&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20men%20such%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20such%20men%20as%3B%2Cc0)

There's nothing grammatically wrong with splitting the element ***such as*** by putting the relevant noun (***lyrics***, here) in between the two words. But even native speakers tend to find it a little bit awkward, so we don't usually do it nowadays, as you can see. Consequently, it sounds somewhat dated/formal.

Comment: @SallySNSD Note, however, that *such* can also act as a determiner, referring without *as* to something which has already been defined, and in this case it must sit before the noun. "Consider these examples . . . Such uses are common in English", NOT "*uses such are common".

Comment: I didn't recognize the cited lyrics fragments you cited, but I now realize [they from Animal Farm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthems_in_Animal_Farm). The text itself is 70 years old, but note that even then the words would have been dated / poetic / ceremonial. Also note that in ordinary spoken contexts today, people are much more likely to talk about *lyrics **like** this*, rather than *lyrics **such as** this*. Though arguably there's sometimes a slight difference in nuance, since the ***like*** version doesn't necessarily *include* whatever "like this" refers to.

Comment: Okay I understand! Thank you for being so careful and patient with me! Thanks a million!